# Cordova app crash when switched in some Androids

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building an hybrid app with cordova (5.1.1) and Ionic (don't think Ionic has any relation with my problem). Every time the user opens another app (in some Androids), when he switches back to my app, the device reloads the app.

I'm trying to find something with the adb console, but I can't find anything that seems to have relation with the problem.

```
adb logcat chromium:D *:S
```

does not log any error, only informs that the app is being opened again, like:

```
I/chromium(13514): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(116)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/BrowserStartupController(13514): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
```

Just "adb logcat" throws a lot of things but nothing that seems to make any sense for me. Anyone has any clue of how to debug this?

Comment: could be a issue with the fragmented and outdated android web view, if you want good consistence performance across all android devices you should build your project with the crosswalk engine. https://crosswalk-project.org/

Comment: @JessPatton thanks for the advice! Actually, I'm avoiding to consider using crosswalk due to the increase in the size app (last time I used, a 4MB app increased to a ~35MB). I noticed that in an Android 5 this not happens, but in two 4.4.X, happened. I'll try other fixed before.

Comment: well it is true the crosswalk project adds a lot to the app but in my opinion the performance boost and consistency is worth every MB.

Comment: @JessPatton I added crosswalk webview to mey project and tried, the problem persist. I guess it has something to do with this device, because it happens with other apps (the reload after resume). Thanks, anyway!

Comment: yeah sorry it didn't help. With weird stuff like that I always check to see if it is the device or the web view.